# PHP Date 2 weeks from now shows incorrect every other week

Tags: php, datetime

I'm displaying a date on a website for a company that has a meeting every other week. The problem I'm having is displaying the next date.

For example, if the current meeting is on the 16th Sep 2014 the date should show 30th Sep 2014.

However when it's less than a week until the 30th Sep 2014 in this example the date will show the week after; 7th Oct 2014 which is incorrect.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php

$dow   = 'tuesday';
$step  = 2;
$unit  = 'W';

$start = new DateTime(gmdate("Y-m-d", time()));
$end   = clone $start;

$start->modify($dow); // Move to first occurence
$end->add(new DateInterval('P1Y')); // Move to 1 year from start

$interval = new DateInterval("P{$step}{$unit}");
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

$count = 0;

echo('<h3>');
foreach ($period as $date) {
    if($count < 1){
        echo $date->format('D, d M Y'), PHP_EOL;
    }
    $count+=1;
}
echo('</h3>');

?>
```

Comment: Can't you use strtotime() ?

Comment: Yes, the method in which you display the time is not the issue. It's showing the correct date e.g. every other tuesday as the current code does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, you could use 
[Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) - well known PHP DateTime Library.  It will handle everything related to DateTime for you. Have a try.

Here is the quick glance at Carbon. To add 2 weeks from now,you can use

`echo Carbon::now()->addWeek(2);`

To Add 2 weeks from given date, say 10th September 2014

`echo Carbon::createFromDate(2014, 9, 10)->addWeek(2);`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Example added James. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the meetings take place every second week, you could rely on the week number.

e.g. if the meeting takes place on Tuesday every even week you could try this:

```
<?php
$today= new DateTime();
$nextTuesday = strtotime("next tuesday");
$week = $today->format("W");

echo("See you on ");
if($week % 2 == 0){
    echo(date("D d/m/Y",strtotime("+7 day", $nextTuesday)));
}
else {
    echo(date("D d/m/Y",$nextTuesday));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code example doesn't match up to your problem description.

Since you use the current timestamp via `new DateTime(gmdate("Y-m-d", time()));` PHP doesn't know when the last meeting was and just calculates 2 weeks from the next Tuesday, *from today*.

The way to do what you describe, using DateTime, is by setting a fixed point in time:

```
$dow  = 'tuesday';
$step = 2;
$unit = 'W';

$start = new DateTime('2014-09-16');
$start->modify($dow);
$start->add(new DateInterval("P{$step}{$unit}"));

echo '<h3>'
    . $start->format('D, d M Y')
    . '</h3>';
```

If you want to output all meeting dates for the next year (as your code seems to show):

```
$dow  = 'tuesday';
$step = 2;
$unit = 'W';

$start = new DateTime('2014-09-16');
$start->modify($dow);

$end = clone $start;
$end->add(new DateInterval('P1Y'));

$interval = new DateInterval("P{$step}{$unit}");

while ($start < $end) {
    $start->add($interval);
    echo '<h3>'
        . $start->format('D, d M Y')
        . '</h3>';
}
```